# Android Studio : Compile time error : Cause: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I tried to create a blank project but the problem is same and then I un-install the Android Studio and re-install it but no difference.
I am using Android Studio - 3.2.1 9th Oct build

Error keep coming : Unable to load class 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils'.

**Android Dependencies in Gradle :**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

**App-Gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.swati.instaclone"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception Trace :**
I am pasting very limited traces here, if required, I will post in details :

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug'.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitList.save(SplitList.java:125)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SplitsDiscovery.taskAction(SplitsDiscovery.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 108 more
```

Comment: I have added i/o links in gradle file like this:
-- implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'

Comment: This is an error in build process, don't add anything to your module dependencies. 1) Try newer `google-services` plugin, 4.1.0 or 4.2.0. 2) Open `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and check the version in `distributionUrl`. `4.10.1-all` is safe for me.

Comment: Thanks, Eugen. It is working fine after changing the distribution url to 4.10.1 -all