# When I run my android studio app on my phone through usb it gives me this error Unable to load class 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils'

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio I made a new project with an empty activity and then it syncs successfully and also builds successfully but when I run the app on my phone(Samsung) via USB it gives me this error below:

```
>Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\whyte\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication7

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions'.
> org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 39s
24 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 21 up-to-date
```

Please note I didn't make any changes to the code, I just open my Android studio and ran the app on my phone. And it gives me this error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok but it's just a normal empty activity project with no changes

Comment: Ok but why do you post an image then? If there's no useful information in it, don't post it. If there is something you want to show, **copy the text** into your question. Also: click on "Build failed" to view (and post) the **full** build output.

Comment: [This question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801862/android-studio-compile-time-error-cause-org-apache-commons-io-fileutils).

Comment: @Joachim Saucer this wasn't helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated my android studio and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.